# Login failed by facebook chat API

Tags: facebook, facebook-chat

I use smack for chat API. Before all worked ok. But now I have issue. On try login to chat server get error: " Your account is temporarily unavailable. Regain access by logging into your account from a web browser".

I try different applications: [FriendCaster Chat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.friendcaster.chat&feature=nav_result), [Go!Chat for Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartancoders.gtok&feature=search_result)
. All also do not worked with my account. Only native application [Chat facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca&feature=search_result) worked normal. But native application use MQTT server, not chat api.

With another account my application worked ok. Issue with my account. But what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is facebook bug and we nothing can todo.